# Возможны ли фразы «эссе утверждает (что это неверно)», «роман повествует (о семье интеллигентов)», «рассказ представляет (новый тип героя)»

Tags: грамотная-речь

Возможны ли фразы «эссе утверждает (что это неверно)», «роман повествует (о семье интеллигентов)», «рассказ представляет (новый тип героя)», где «форма» произведения выступает «действующим лицом»?

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке подобные выражения звучат нелепо: по-русски утверждает автор работы, но не сама работа. По-английски – да, this article doubts that... – совершенно нормальная формулировка.

Comment: Согласен, что "эссе утверждает" звучит несколько непривычно. Но выражения "роман повествует", "повесть рассказывает", "рассказ описывает" и т.п. можно встретить в каждом номере "Литературной газеты", например.

Comment: @grizzly может, это особенности языка литературных критиков, не сталкивался. В нейтральном контексте я бы так не сказал всё равно.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку даны три примера конструкции - то имеем и три вопроса, допускающие разные ответы.
В целом я бы сказал, что первый вариант ("эссе утверждает") сомнителен, второй  ("роман повествует") - приемлем, а третий ("рассказ представляет") - не хорош.

И дело, понятно, не только и даже не столько в том, что это разные "формы" (или жанры) и они по-разному соотносятся с такими глаголами как "утверждать" или "представлять" (эссе вообще в наименьшей степени свойственно что-то утверждать), тут дело в самих глаголах.

"Рассказывать" - вполне нейтрально, скажем выражения типа "привычка человека может рассказать о его характере" не вызывают вопросов. "Рассказать" - это просто сделать доступной некую информацию, фактическую или эмоциональную. Так почему рассказ или повесть или эссе не годятся на роль проводника такой информации? Разве что некоторая тавтологичность получается "рассказ рассказывает" или "повесть повествует", но это можно за скобки вынести.

"Утверждать", напротив, несколько сомнительно для художественной литературы. Была бы эта научная статья - вопросов бы не было. Тем более - теорема ("Теорема Ферма утверждает то-то и то-то"). А для беллетристики "утверждать" как-то не свойственно. Разве что в особом смысле: "Роман утверждает торжество идей справедливости". Но это все-таки не то утверждение, о котором речь в примерах.

И наконец "[Рассказ] представляет". Я вижу тут стилистический ляп, косноязычие даже. Можно смириться, что представляют не конкретное лицо как это подразумевалось ранее. *"Кинокомпания "Всё продакшн" представляет фильм "Всех купившн"* - еще годится. Но у нас совсем не этот случай. Как вообще рассказ может "представить" героя? Представить кого-тот идиотом, наверное, может. Но просто представить? Нет, я этого не могу взять в толк.

ПС. Вот я написал ответ в виде некоего эссе, без претензий на доказательность. Это повествование? Ну да есть в некотором смысле, хотя больше на рассуждение похоже, как и всякое эссе. Утверждение? Да, пожалуй. Но кого и как я тут представил? Только свое видение, никак не героя.